# Django Admin - Show ManyToOne data on a model in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have 2 models `Patient` and `History`.
I would like to show all `History` of a `Patient` inside the `Patient` model in django admin as table. I was thinking to use ManyToOne field as one patient can have more than 1 history and 1 history is only owned by 1 patient. In the `Patient` model admin I would like to also be able to add a new history.
I have tried to use ManyToMany field but doesn't looks like the solution.
Can anyone please help me on how to solve this?

Below is the code:

```py
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class History(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    diagnosis = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`InlineModelAdmin objects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to achieve this functionality, they allows us to edit models related to the parent model in the same form as the parent model.

Try the following:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Patient, History

@admin.register(History)
class HistoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class HistoryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = History
    extra = 1

@admin.register(Patient)
class PatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [HistoryInline]
```